# how to filter datalist table of wordpress

Tags: filters

```
function custom_filter() {
    global $typenow;
    global $wp_query;
        if ( $typenow == 'invitation_code' ) { // Your custom post type slug
        $plugins = array( 'Searh-By-dealer-role', 'Searh-By-distributer-role','Used code','availabel code'); // Options for the filter select field
        $current_plugin = '';
        if( isset( $_GET['slug'] ) ) {
            $current_plugin = $_GET['slug']; // Check if option has been selected
        } ?>
        <select name="slug" id="slug">
            <option value="all" <?php selected( 'all', $current_plugin ); ?>><?php _e( 'All', 'wisdom-plugin' ); ?></option>
            <?php foreach( $plugins as $key=>$value ) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr( $key ); ?>" <?php selected( $key, $current_plugin ); ?>><?php echo esc_attr( $value ); ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    <?php }
    }

    function custom_filter_data_by_slug( $query ) {
    global $pagenow;
    global $wpdb;
    // Get the post type
    $post_type = isset( $_GET['post_type'] ) ? $_GET['post_type'] : '';

    if ( is_admin() && $pagenow=='edit.php' && $post_type == 'invitation_code' && isset( $_GET['slug'] ) && $_GET['slug'] !='all' ) {

        if($_GET['slug'] == "0")//search by dealer
        {
            $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'userrole';
            $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = 'dealer';



        }
        elseif($_GET['slug']== "1")//search by distributer
        {
            $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'userrole';
            $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = 'distributors';


        }
        elseif($_GET['slug']== "2")//used code
        {

            $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'userlimit';
            $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = '0';

        }
        elseif($_GET['slug']== "3")
        {
            //add_filter('posts_where','data_where',10,2);
            //below code not working

            $sql12 = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN(SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='userlimit' and meta_value > 0)";
            $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql12);
            return $results;


        }

    }
    }



}


$this->loader->add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', $plugin_admin, 'custom_filter' );
$this->loader->add_filter('parse_query',$plugin_admin,'custom_filter_data_by_slug');
```

this hooks are used

but the code written in slug ==3 are not working..

Answer (score 0):

And why should it work?

`parse_query` is an action, not a filter. This action takes `$query` (`WP_Query` object) as argument and lets you modify it.

Now, take a look at your code if slug equals 3:

```
$sql12 = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN(SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='userlimit' and meta_value > 0)";
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql12);
return $results;
```

You don't modify `$query` object, so this code won't affect the queried posts.

If I understand your intention correctly, you want to get all posts, where value of meta `userlimit` is greater than 0? In such case you have to modify `$query` this way:

```
elseif($_GET['slug']== "3")
{
    $query->set( 'meta_key', 'userlimit' );
    $query->set( 'meta_value_num', 0 );
    $query->set( 'meta_compare', '>' );
}
```

PS. Also you shouldn't modify `query_vars` directly for other cases. Use setter function like in the code above instead.